# How can I get the kubectl proxy to the kubernetes dashboard working?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I'm setting up a highly available microk8s cluster on three servers running ubuntu server 20.04.
I enabled the dashboard addon and tried to forward it using the command

```sh
kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443
```

in WSL Ubuntu with the microk8s cluster configured in the kubeconfig file, but it returned the error

```sh
error: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 192.168.250.235:10250: connect: no route to host
```

so then I tried running `microk8s dashboard-proxy` on one of the servers to see if that would work, and it returned the error

```sh
Checking if Dashboard is running.
Dashboard will be available at https://127.0.0.1:10443
Use the following token to login:
<TOKEN>
error: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 192.168.250.235:10250: connect: no route to host
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/microk8s/1710/scripts/wrappers/dashboard-proxy.py", line 80, in <module>
    dashboard_proxy()
  File "/snap/microk8s/1710/scripts/wrappers/dashboard-proxy.py", line 74, in dashboard_proxy
    check_output(command)
  File "/snap/microk8s/1710/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/snap/microk8s/1710/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/snap/microk8s/current/microk8s-kubectl.wrapper', 'port-forward', '-n', 'kube-system', 'service/kubernetes-dashboard', '10443:443', '--address', '0.0.0.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The addons dashboard, dns, ha-cluster, helm3 and metrics-server are enabled in the microk8s cluster.

`kubectl get nodes` returns the following output:

```
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
esx02   Ready    <none>   93m    v1.19.2-34+1b3fa60b402c1c
esx03   Ready    <none>   87m    v1.19.2-34+1b3fa60b402c1c
esx01   Ready    <none>   101m   v1.19.2-34+1b3fa60b402c1c
```

esx01 has the ip 192.168.250.51, esx02 the IP 192.168.250.52 and esx03 the IP 192.168.250.53.

the output of `kubectl -n kube-system describe service/kubernetes-dashboard` is:

```sh
Name:              kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.152.183.174
Port:              <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.40.194:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Can you run `kubectl -n kube-system describe service/kubernetes-dashboard` ?

Comment: here is the result:
`Name:              kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.152.183.174
Port:              <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.40.194:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
`

Comment: Have you tried port-forwarding the pod instead?

Comment: port-forwarding the pod results in the same error, but using `kubectl proxy` and visiting http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ works and the dashboard opens.

Comment: But portforwarding doesn't work and also nginx-ingress doesn't work, when i visit the ip there is no nginx 404 error but nothing

Comment: You should set up the service with a NodePort type. This way, each node will accept connections and forward them to them correct pod. ClusterIP only works internally on the kubernetes network.